# Why is my UICollectionViewCell touch event offset ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView that is using the Flow Layout. At this point I'm not really doing anything special. I'm just programmatically adding the view and the UICollectionViewCell.

When you touch a cell it is registering the touch event for the cell that is located above it. So if you touch a cell on row 2 the the cell above is the one that actually registers the touch.

Here is the code that I have setting things up.

```
@interface KFYSearch() <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UISearchBarDelegate>

@property(nonatomic, strong)UISearchBar *searchBar;
@property(nonatomic, strong)UICollectionView *collectionView;
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSArray *collectionData;

@end

@implementation KFYSearch


-(id)initWithView:(UIView*)view
{
    self = [super init];

    if(self)
        self.view = view;

    return self;
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if(_searchBar == nil)
    {
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, self.view.superview.frame.size.width - 40, self.view.superview.frame.size.height - 40);
        [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];


        [self createChildViews];
    }

}


-(void)createChildViews
{
    _searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(5, 5, self.view.frame.size.width - 10, 30)];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];

    _collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(_searchBar.frame.origin.x, _searchBar.frame.origin.y + (_searchBar.frame.size.height + 2), _searchBar.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - ((_searchBar.frame.origin.y + _searchBar.frame.size.height) + 10)) collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];

    _collectionView.dataSource = self;
    _collectionView.delegate = self;

    [_collectionView registerClass:[KFYKlickableCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    [_collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    [self.view addSubview:_searchBar];
    [self.view addSubview:_collectionView];

    [self getData];
}


-(void)getData
{
    KFYGetKlickablesAction *getKlickablesAction = [[KFYGetKlickablesAction alloc]init];
    _collectionData = [getKlickablesAction mockData];

    [_collectionView reloadData];
}


#pragma UICollectionView Delegate stuff;

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _collectionData.count;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

// The cell that is returned must be retrieved from a call to -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    KFYKlickableCell *cell= [_collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    KFYKlickableVO *vo = [_collectionData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell renderKlickable:vo];

    return (UICollectionViewCell*)cell;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    return CGSizeMake(60, 60);
}

-(UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5);
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    KFYKlickableVO *vo = [_collectionData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(vo.tag);
}

#pragma UITextField Delegate stuff

-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    //Keyboard becomes visible
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,
                                  self.view.frame.origin.y,
                                  self.view.frame.size.width,
                                  self.view.frame.size.height - 215 + 50);   //resize
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    //keyboard will hide
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,
                                  self.view.frame.origin.y,
                                  self.view.frame.size.width,
                                  self.view.frame.size.height + 215 - 50); //resize
}


@end
```

Comment: The selection triggers the function `-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` and not `didDeselect`

Comment: That was the issue. good catch. Thanks.